# how to system restore windows 7 with clean boot

Tags: windows-7, boot, restore, system-restore, windows-7-restore

I want to restore a computer running windows 7. My goal swipe it clean and then re-install windows 7 with the same product key.
To do I understand that I need to create a recovery drive (on USB preferably) 
My question are:

1.Is it possible to make it so that when I make the recovery drive It makes it a clean boot such as only the minimal, no extra programs, files etc.

2. How much space will this take? as in how big should the USB be?

Comment: If you want to just do a clean installation forget about the recovery drive, its not required, just use an installation disk for the Windows 7 version your using and just install it using your OEM key.

Comment: I don't have the installation disk however. It came installed on the computer

Comment: There exists a question with a direct link to every version of windows 7 on this website.  The recovery disk can't be used to Install windows

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to retain the same license and OS after full wipe. You can take disk level image backup of this machine or only the c drive where OS install using any backup software and restore it on the disk after complete wipe.

Comment: Thanks for your awnser but I think I figured out I can do a factory setting restore which I believe is what I need